# Error al subir archivo mediante type="file"

Tags: php, entrada

Tengo un gran problema que es bastante extraño, tengo un `input type="file"` en mi web, en el cual los usuarios pueden subir una foto de un documento. Lo que me pasa es que a veces desde un móvil, al utilizar el `input` para subir una foto desde la cámara, a veces se sube correctamente y otras no.

El problema no es a la hora de completar el `form` y subir el documento al servidor, si no a la hora de seleccionar el archivo y dejarlo dentro del `input`. Cuando hago la foto y le doy a aceptar/enviar, en vez de ponerme el nombre del archivo en el `input`, me refresca la página, os dejo el pequeño código con el `input`.

```html
<p>
  <form id="carga_archivo" name="carga_archivo" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST" style="padding: 0; margin-top: 20px;">
  
     <input type="file" id="file-input" name="uploadedfile">
     <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" style="display: none;">
     <input id="albaran" name="albaran" type="number" placeholder="Nº de Albarán" style="text-align: center; height: 50px;" required>
     <input type="submit" value="SUBIR Y COMPLETAR AVISO" style="background:#1e81e6; color:white;font-weight: bold;height: 45px;" />
     
   </form>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tengo una sugerencia simple:

1. Ubica un llamador ajax que pase una notificación al servidor indicando que vas a enviar una foto (que está por tomar)
2. cuando el servidor responde a la notificación, el método registrado para .success o .done abre la camara como lo hacía tu click.
3. Cuando el servidor reciba la solicitud de la página para ser recargada encuentra un flag indicando que hay proceso a medio-camino.
4. Se sirve entonces una página modificada cuyo evento onload tiene registrada y lanza la función que completa la tarea y que no se podía completar por recarga.
5. Cuando la página sea enviada y guardada borra el flag y su respuesta recarga la versión original, sin onload para evitar problemas de reiteraciones fallidas.

Espero sirva la sugerencia.

Ah me olvidaba, el a veces es un problema de cache: unas veces lee en el otras no.

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente es un problema del dispositivo móvil y no de tu aplicación, así que poco podrás hacer para solucionarlo.
He encontrado [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274727/android-browser-refreshes-page-after-selecting-file-via-input-element) en SO en inglés preguntando por lo mismo, y parece ser que el escenario es el siguiente:

1. Tienes la página cargada y quieres usar la aplicación de la cámara (o cualquier otra) para seleccionar un archivo para subirlo.
2. Esta segunda aplicación pasa a estar en primer plano, mientras el navegador está en segundo plano, esperando.
3. Quizá porque esta aplicación ocupa mucha memoria RAM o sencillamente porque el SO decide que tiene que liberar memoria, las aplicaciones en segundo plano se cierran.
4. Has seleccionado la foto y es enviada a la aplicación del navegador. El navegador se abre, recordando la página (la URL) pero no el contenido de la misma, con lo que se refresca, perdiendo los datos introducidos hasta ese momento.

Por tanto no hay mucho que puedas hacer para resolverlo, hay quejas de usuarios a los que les pasa hoy día incluso con móviles con 8GB de RAM.

Comment: Lo curioso es que a veces falla a veces no, por ejemplo en mi movil casi nunca falla, y en otros moviles incluso mejores que el mio falla. Normalmente falla la primera o segunda vez que lo intentas, la tercera ya te deja